# C++ How do i split this into vector and use it

Tags: c++, split

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Splitting a string in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/splitting-a-string-in-c)

I am doing client server programming using C++.

My client sends a string with the value

```
string receiveClient = "auth#user:pass";
```

How do I split the `receiveClient` variable by `'#'` and `':'` as delimiters?

---

I have tried to use this function I found online

```
vector split (const string &s,char delim)
{
  vector string elems;
  return(s,delim,elems);
}
```

and I did this at `main()`:

```
vector x = split(&receiveClient,"#");
```

But it return me the following

```
server.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
server.cpp:128:8: error: missing template arguments before ‘x’
server.cpp:128:8: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘x’
root@ubuntu:/home/baoky/csci222_assn2# g++ server server.cpp
server.cpp:47:1: error: invalid use of template-name ‘std::vector’ without an argument list
server.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
server.cpp:128:8: error: missing template arguments before ‘x’
server.cpp:128:8: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘x’
```

Thanks for all help. greatly appreciated

Comment: Some of the answers here you may find useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11374617/the-easiest-way-to-read-formatted-input-in-c

Comment: I have no idea where you found that function online, but it's just completely useless because it doesn't compile, and it doesn't make sense. I recommend you avoid that source in the future (could tell what is that source so we can avoid it too?)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, looking at the posted code I think <string> etc. has been interpreted as an HTML tag somewhere.

Comment: @john that doesn't help in the least. It makes it compile and... do nonsense.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes It might if it's the OP who's made that mistake.

Comment: @user: I have tried to improve the question a bit. Feel free to fix if my interpretations of what you wanted was off the mark.

Answer (score 3):

Such tasks are usually easiest done using streams in C++. Something like this should work:

```
// Beware, brain-compiled code ahead!

#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

std::vector<string> splitClientAuth(const std::string& receiveClient)
{
  // "auth#user:pass"
  std::istringstream iss(receiveClient);

  std::vector<std::string> strings;
  strings.resize(3);
  std::getline(iss, strings[0], '#');
  std::getline(iss, strings[1], ':');
  std::getline(iss, strings[2]); // default is '\n'

  if( !iss && !iss.eof() )
    throw "Dude, you badly need an error handling strategy!";

  if( string[0].empty() || string[1].empty() || string[2].empty() )
    throw "Watcha gonna do now?";

  return strings;
}
```

---

A few additional point worth noting:

- Are those really ***plain-text passwords***?
- Having this in a `std::vector<std::string>` seems dubious to me. If that was my code, I'd want ***a data structure to store user information***, and write what I find write into that.
- Judging from you totally failing to understand the code you pasted in your question (Martinho is right, that's so bad, it's arguable whether it can still be considered C++), and from your comments, ***you seem to be in bad need of a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)***.

Answer (score 2):

The code you've found online is garbage. Try this

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

vector<string> split(const string& s, char delim)
{
  vector<string> elems(2);
  string::size_type pos = s.find(delim);
  elems[0] = s.substr(0, pos);
  elems[1] = s.substr(pos + 1);
  return elems;
}
```

This is untested code, and it doesn't do any error checking (for instance what if `s` does not contain `delim`). I'll leave you do sort that out.

You call the function like this

```
vector<string> x = split(receiveClient, '#');
```

Comment: ... and it probably needs an `#include <vector>`, `#include <string>` and a `using namespace std;` somewhere.

Comment: How do i run your code i tried vector x = split(&receiveClient,"#");

Comment: ewww, `using namespace std;`.

Comment: @john: [You should](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1453605/140719).

Comment: I written hundreds of thousands of lines of code, and I've probably introduced tens of thousands of bugs. But I have never ever had a bug caused by `using namespace std;` in a cpp file. It's just not an issue.

Comment: no one is gong to mention the split in boost ? ^_^

Comment: @john: [It does happen](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2712125/140719), though.