# (C++) Issue with overloading ">>" operator

Tags: c++

Once I try to compile and run program, visual shows this error.

> Error 1   error C2679: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const char [2]' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Overload function:

```
istream& operator>> (istream& InputStream, Description& rhs) {
InputStream >> rhs.mNumber >> "," >> rhs.mLenght >> "," >> rhs.mName;

return InputStream;
}
```

Class Description defintion:

```
class Description {
private:
    int mNumber;
    int mLenght;
    string mName;
public:
    Description();
    Description(int, int, string);
    Description& operator= (const Description&);
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream&, Description&);
    friend istream& operator>> (istream&, Description&);
};
```

And yes I did:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <istream>
```

Comment: The code as written attempts to read from `InputStream` and assign something to `","` which is `const` and can't be assigned to.

Comment: "And yes I did" but what you did not is to provide [mcve]

Comment: "And yes I did" -- okay, but I didn't. If you want people to help you, provide code that shows the problem. I won't cut and paste to create something that might or might not be what you tried. You know what you did; post it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11374617/the-easiest-way-to-read-formatted-input-in-c

Comment: What do you want `InputStream >> ","` to do? If that worked, it would assign a new value to the constant `","`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line

```
InputStream >> rhs.mNumber >> "," >> rhs.mLenght >> "," >> rhs.mName;
```

the `","` parts are wrong. You can't read anything into a string literal.

If you expect to see the token `,` in the input stream, you may use:

```
char dummy;
InputStream >> rhs.mNumber >> dummy >> rhs.mLenght >> dummy >> rhs.mName;
```